# What vendros have the longest support policies?

Tags: updates

I've always stuck to stock android and preferrably googles nexus/pixel devices because I want access to future updates, primarily security but also features. (currently i'm running a nexus 6p)

But I need a phone right now, and the new pixel will likely not be out until October. I've been looking at the onePlus but can't find if they have any support policies or best practices for their oxygen os. Who are best in class? I don't mind paying a bit extra if the phone will stay up to date for longer.

Comment: I'm not sure why users pushed this question to hold. Anyways, the best answer I can give is of Nokia. They are the only OEM who is seriously committed to delivering Android & security updates month on month. Most of their devices are Android One certified and hence you are good to receive at least 2 years of security updates. I'm however, not sure if you will be able to find a device with Pixel like capabilities from Nokia. There is the Nokia 8 Sirocco which kinda looks dated. The 7 Plus is great device but I'm not sure if that's a pixel replacement for you.

Comment: @singhnsk As the explanation says, **this question is Android-independent**.